# GPUImage with MacOS - how to save processed file to disk

Tags: swift3, gpuimage, nsimage

I'm currently porting bits of code from CoreImage to GPUImage and having a problem saving processed file to disk. While this worked with CoreImage:

```
guard
    let blurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur"),
    let imageURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "my-image", withExtension: "png"),
    let ciImage = CIImage(contentsOf: imageURL)
else {
    return
}

blurFilter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
blurFilter.setValue(100, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)

guard
    let result = blurFilter.outputImage,
    let cgImage = context.createCGImage(result, from: result.extent)
else {
    return
}

let destinationURL = desktopURL.appendingPathComponent("output.png")
let nsImage = NSImage(cgImage: cgImage, size: ciImage.extent.size)
```

The following code ported to GPUImage:

```
let testImage = NSImage(named:"my-image.png")!
let blurFilter = GaussianBlur()
let filteredImage = testImage.filterWithOperation(blurFilter)

let desktopURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .desktopDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let destinationURL = desktopURL.appendingPathComponent("output.png")
let nsImage = NSImage(nsImage: filteredImage, size: filteredImage.extent.size)
```

Gives the following error message pertaining to the last line:

```
Value type of 'NSImage' has no member 'extent'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filteredImage` is an NSImage. In your Core Image code, `ciImage` is a, well, CIImage. CIImage has an `extent` property, NSImage does not.

There's no need to create `nsImage` in your second code, `filteredImage` is already an NSImage. You're done.